# How to have callback change variable of class without using global variable?

Tags: c++, class, callback

I have a function that takes another function as a callback, but need the callback to be a part of a class as a non-static method, because I have to change a specific variable with the callback.

The problem is that the `setCallback()` function doesn't want a method function but a normal, static function.

I get that the `setCallback()` function can't just use the class function as is since it doesn't know which object to call and the syntax for classes is different.
I know that I also could solve this with a global variable, but I really don't want to have to use them and I've been told that it *is* possible to do anything without globals.

Note: the `setCallback()` function is from a library and I have no way to change it.

header.h

```
class myClass
{
    int classVariable;

    myClass();
    
    callbackFunction(int callbackVariable);
}
```

source.cpp

```
myClass::myClass()
{
    library::setCallback(this.callbackFunction); // ???
}
    
myClass::callbackFunction(int callbackVariable)
{
    classVariable = callbackVariable;
}
```

where `setCallback()` looks like:

```
library::setCallback(void (*)(int callbackVariable));
```

Edit:
Turns out there was a library specific solution to this

Comment: Which is the signature of `setCallback`?

Comment: It's a function from a library I'm using, edited for clarification

Comment: Since the library function wants a normal static function, you can't provide it a member function.

Comment: @jon That doesn't really help. What library are you using? Libraries often let you set a user pointer specifically for providing context to the callback.

Comment: You don't answer to the question... Is it `void setCallback(std::function<void(int)>)`, `void setCallback(void(*)(int, void*), void* userData)`?

Comment: You are maybe confusing what is global, what is translation unit local, what is thread local and what is class static member. Figure out the differences, then there are no problems.

Comment: If the callback interface doesn't provide a pointer-sized parameter that is free for client use I like using libffi for this pattern, unlike lambdas using libffi it is possible to create function pointers with arbitrary interfaces that also capture data. If the callback interface does provide such a parameter then a lambda is an excellent shim between the client and library, just use that parameter for 'this' and have your lambda call into a member function.

Comment: The `setCallback()` fucntion uses some typedef and I'm not entirely sure what it means but it looks like: `typedef void(* callbackFunc)(int callbackVariable)`, and `setCallback(callbackFunc func)`, so I suspect its the latter one, sorry for confusion I am not the most experienced programmer @Jarod42

Comment: @LHLaurini using glfw, this specifically is for the window resize callback

Comment: @jon Then use [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) to set a user pointer.

Comment: @LHLaurini This worked, thanks! I suppose I should've made it clear in my question what library I was using, I thought the would be a more general solution to it, but thank you!